# DocuSign: The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed

Tags: node.js, token, docusignapi

I cloned the NodeJS [DocuSign example repo](https://github.com/docusign/qs-02-node-send-envelope), I did update the `.env` file with my Account ID and generated token as described in this official video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADmELHcPpbM.

When I run thier demo, I get:

```
{
    "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN",
    "message": "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."
}
```

Despite their page shows that the token is valid for 6h. I contacted support, but they don't provide technical support, and they redirected me here.

Comment: which url did you use when you got the above error?

Comment: This is their sample project linked from their developer website: https://github.com/docusign/qs-02-node-send-envelope/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I mean your app, when you call DocuSign. you make an API call, what is the URL?

Comment: this error, in some cases, means you didn't provide the correct userId. With JWT, the API call must also provide the userId (GUID) to impersonate is. Can you check that you have that configured correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing `api_client.setBasePath('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi');`. But this still doesn't work with the official provided example code.

Answer (score -1):

I think sometimes key is not get copied successfully by using select and ctrl+c. Try to use "copy to clipboard" button on their site.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRqBu.png)